# Allow subdomains with Firefox canvas fingerprinting

Tags: firefox, permissions, privacy

Firefox [has fingerprinting protection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-protection-against-fingerprinting) (currently experimental). Some sites that use the canvas don't render properly. For example, the terminal in [GitHub Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces) looks garbled until an exception is added. You can add exceptions for sites that you trust.

Codespaces in particular becomes difficult to use: each space is given its own subdomain like `your-space.github.dev`, so when granting permission to read from the canvas, it only applies to *that* space. Creating a new space becomes an awkward dance of create, wait for it to be created and load, add permission, reload, wait for it to reconnect.

#### How can I add canvas permission for any subdomain of `github.dev`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that subdomains inherit the canvas permission from their parents<sup>1</sup>, so you just need to allow it for `github.dev`. Unfortunately in this case, `github.dev` doesn't use a canvas so Firefox doesn't give the option to allow it. Instead:

1. Create a Codespace.
2. [Grant it permission to read the canvas](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-protection-against-fingerprinting).
3. Backup your `permissions.sqlite` in your [profile directory](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data).
4. Modify your profile's `permissions.sqlite` file<sup>2</sup> to remove the subdomain from the `github.dev` entry. For example, using `sqlite3`:

   ```bash
   sqlite3 permissions.sqlite
   ```

   ```sql
   update moz_perms
     set origin = "https://github.dev"
     where origin = "https://your-space.github.dev";
   ```

<sup>1</sup> *The permission [is checked with `TestPermissionFromPrincipal`](https://github.com/bolucat/Firefox/blob/60ba0341328fbee43369c0b409c6a94a182eef99/dom/canvas/CanvasUtils.cpp#L122), which [doesn't require an exact hostname match](https://github.com/bolucat/Firefox/blob/8632a1522f80f2df4989cb2beb57c1ed3ae7827e/extensions/permissions/PermissionManager.cpp#L2281), so if the permission isn't set for a subdomain the parent domain is also checked.*

<sup>2</sup> *Editing the permissions database is [described in this Bugzilla comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1432644#c27)*.